# Converting ascii Russian to Russian?

Tags: windows-7, language, unicode, ascii

I have a text document that is supposed to be written in Russian but it seems to instead be ascii:

```
Óñòàíîâêà:
1)Çàïóñêàåì QuidamStudioSetup3.15.exe
2)Ïðè çàïðîñå ñåðèéíîãî íîìåðà ââîäèì
```

How could I convert this to unicode Russian characters that are readable?

Comment: Open the file in MS Word. It can guess the encoding correctly most of the time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is *not* "ASCII" nor "ASCII Russian".

Before Unicode became widespread, most computer systems used the ISO-8859 character encodings, of which there were 16, each for a different region (Central European, Cyrillic, Greek...). Windows had its own 'code pages', very similar but with extra glyphs in otherwise-unused ranges. All these character encodings are 8-bit and only differ in the second half (128-255).

The problem with these encodings is that it's next to impossible for a program to determine *which* encoding was used to save a file, unless it was specified explicitly (such as in HTML pages; however, plain text files have no such metadata tags). Read the Wikipedia article on [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) for a more detailed description.

In your example, the document was saved using **Windows-1251** (Cyrillic), but your program reads it as if it were **Windows-1252** (Western European), which has very different characters in the same positions. To the computer, it looks perfectly okay – it doesn't understand languages or scripts. (There are programs which do statistical analysis in order to determine the correct encoding, though – some web browsers have such a function.)

There are several ways you could convert such text to Unicode:

- Use **online tools such as [this one](http://2cyr.com/decode/)** or [this one](http://decodr.ru/).
- Use your web browser:

  1. Drag the `.txt` file into the browser.
  2. From *View → Character Encoding* (or *Firefox → Web Developer → Character Encoding*, or *Wrench → Tools → Encoding*), pick the correct original encoding: "Cyrillic (Windows-1251)" in your case.
- Use the [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) text editor:

  1. Open the file.
  2. From *File → Encoding → Recode...*, choose the right original encoding.
- Use GNU `iconv`, with Windows binaries either from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) or [Gettext for Win32](http://gettext.sourceforge.net/).

  ```
  iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 < myfile.txt > myfile.fixed.txt
  ```

  Windows Notepad will correctly read UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoded text.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the encoding using a program such as [iconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) - but you'll need to know what encoding was used.

It seems to be Windows-1251 according to a [random web page](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) found by Google.

> Установка:
>   1) Запускаем QuidamStudioSetup3.15.exe
>   2) При запросе серийного номера вводим

I don't know Russian but pasting that into translate.google.com suggests that the above is plausible:

> installation:
>   1) Run QuidamStudioSetup3.15.exe
>   2) When prompted, enter the serial number

So ...

```
iconv -f 1252 -t UTF-8 document.txt
```

Should convert your test file into something that can be opened and read in Notepad

Comment: I know Russian and you're right, it's Windows-1251.