# Is there a way to change my ASCII language in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, language, unicode

If I'm not mistaken, there are symbols in ASCII those differ depending on language.
For example, on my computer the default language for Windows 7 is Russian. So, I can save text files like "абацаба"using ANSI in notepad.
Also, this script shows russian characters from 128th in IDE not supporting unicode

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<256;++i)
    {
        printf("%d - %c\n",i,char(i));
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

My laptop has Windows 8 with English default language. When I send russian text files saved in ASCII to it, it doesn't show them correctly. (However, I can print and save russian characters in unicode). 
Switching some of my applications to unicode seems very complicated, so can I change ascii, without reinstalling Win8?

Comment: Related: [Converting ascii Russian to Russian?](http://superuser.com/questions/343782/converting-ascii-russian-to-russian?rq=1)

Comment: I've moved Russian to the top of control panel -> all control panel items -> Language. Russian texts are still not recognized. Does it mean single language installation (I added Russian myself, by default there was only english)?

Comment: Oh, it's displayed in my computer - > properties. Single Language. Thanks.

Comment: @ser2136963 - If I am not mistaken your license is valid for any version of `Windows 8 Single Language` this means you could request an image of the Russian version easily enough from your OEM.  I still find it odd that you find yourself with an English version of Single Language consider its normally limited to your region in more historically spoken languages ( i.e. Russian itself ).

Comment: It says as much in @techie007's link above, but ASCII, ANSI and UNICODE are three different things. ASCII is strictly limited to 128 glyphs and control characters. Unicode and UTF are mulit-byte character encoding schemes. In most cases "nobody cares", but in this question, the differences are important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite my Windows is single language edition, I managed to change locale in

`Control panel -> all control panel items -> Language->advanced settings -> Apply language settings to the welcome screen, system accounts, and new user accounts->Administrative->Change system Locale`